# How to import matplotlib with the matplotlib installed

Tags: python, import, command

C:>pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in **strong text**c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.12.0)

C:>python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import matplotlib
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py", line 200, in 
> > >           _check_versions()
> > >         File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py", line 194, in _check_versions
> > >           module = importlib.import_module(modname)
> > >         File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
> > >           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> > >       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

two days ago was a new release of matplotlib-3.1.1
should work fine (it was in my case) after upgrading it with (if on windows 10):

```
pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib
```